# Android back button disabled when using searchbar widget

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

In NativeScript-Vue the SearchBar widget seems to override the back button in Android. The desired behavior is for the back button to close the keyboard and then, if pressed once more, navigate back to the page the user was on before. What happens instead is that the keyboard closes and then subsequent back button presses do nothing. This only happens once the SearchBar has focus.

I've tried registering a listener

```
mounted: function(){
    if(application.android){
        application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, this.backEvent);
    }
}
```

That approach worked on other pages but it seems to be completely ignored once the searchBar has focus. Is there a way to capture the back button press event from the searchbar?

Here is the vue template:

```
<template>
<Page class="page">
    <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout class="home-panel">
           <SearchBar id="mySearchBar" @loaded="onLoadedEvent" hint="Search hint" v-model="searchPhrase"  @submit="onSearchSubmit" />

            <ListView class="list-group" for="country in filteredList" @itemTap="onItemTap" style="height:1250px">
                <v-template>
                    <GridLayout columns="*, 2*" rows="auto, auto" class="list-group-item">
                        <Image col="0"  rowSpan="2" :src="country.imageSrc" />
                        <Label col="1" colSpan="2" row="0" :text="country.name" class="list-group-item-heading" />
                        <label col="1" colSpan="2" row="1" :text="country.description" />
                    </GridLayout>
                </v-template>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

inside the script tag I have the appropriate imports and then the following inside export default:

```
methods: {

    onLoadedEvent(args){
        if(application.android){
            args.object.android.clearFocus();

        }   

    },
    onItemTap: function (args) {
        console.log('Item with index: ' + this.countries[args.index].name + ' tapped');
        console.log("Value of searchPhrase: " + this.searchPhrase);

    },

    onSearchSubmit(args) {
        let searchBar = args.object;
        console.log("You are searching for " + searchBar.text);
    },
    onClearEvent(args){
        let searchBar = args.object;

    }
},
computed: {
    filteredList() {
        return this.countries.filter(country => {
            return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchPhrase.toLowerCase())
        })
    }
},
data () {
    return {
        countries: [
            { name: "Australia",        description: "Snakes and stuff",        imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/au.png" },
            { name: "Belgium",          description: "Great Waffles",           imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/be.png" },
            { name: "Bulgaria",         description: "No Clue. Maybe Dracula?", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/bg.png" },
            { name: "Canada",           description: "Maple Syrup",             imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ca.png" },
            { name: "Switzerland",      description: "Chocolate & Watches",     imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ch.png" },
            { name: "China",            description: "Socialism",               imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/cn.png" },
            { name: "Czech Republic",   description: "Checkers?",               imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/cz.png" },
            { name: "Germany",          description: "AHH, Motherland!",        imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/de.png" },
            { name: "Spain",            description: "Bulls!",                  imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/es.png" },
            { name: "Ethiopia",         description: "Hungry",                  imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/et.png" },
            { name: "Croatia",          description: "Crows?",                  imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/hr.png" },
            { name: "Hungary",          description: "Hung Gary",               imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/hu.png" },
            { name: "Italy",            description: "Meatballs",               imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/it.png" },
            { name: "Jamaica",          description: "Ganja",                   imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/jm.png" },
            { name: "Romania",          description: "Not Romans",              imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ro.png" },
            { name: "Russia",           description: "Putin 4 Life",            imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ru.png" },
            { name: "United States",    description: "Fat People",              imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/us.png" },
        ],

        searchPhrase: ""

    };
}
```

Comment: Do you have the search bar as an ActionItem? Can you share the Playground sample?

Comment: Here's the link to the playground demo and thank you in advance.                                                                        https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=ZkT6zn

Comment: I guess it's the new AndroidX SearchView with {N} 6, you might want to report same on Github. A quick solution could be expanding and collapsing search view with ActionBar.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll give it a try.